# Animation Nodes : Tumbling dominos along a spline

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm banging my head against an issue I can't solve.
I distribute dominos along a spline using Animation Nodes. So far so good, it's extremely simple and works very well.
What I can't achieve is making the dominos fall by rotating its X axis locally and not globally.
This image sums up my problem :

[image]

The Offset Matrix does the job but rotate the dominos on the world axis, not the local axis.
How can I solve this issue ? I've tried combining matrices, multiplying them, to no avail...

Thanks !

Comment: would you provide your blend file, so we don't have to rebuild everything for testing?

Answer (score 0):

In the *Advanced Option* (left panel) you need to change the *Transform Order* to *Local*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)